# mysql. is it normal if there are too many relations in one db?

Tags: mysql

I have db that has(will have) many tables(planing 70), and about 50 of them will have two or three relations. is it normal and will it affect to the speed or to something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this kind of question is very dependent on the data being represented. If performance does become an issue, you can have relations but not have them enforced by the database, just formally documented and enforced in code that manipulates that data; this way you avoid the cost of checking and enforcing foreign keys, at the cost of requiring more vigilance when manipulating data to keep that data coherent. However, doing away with foreign keys before you need to is premature optimization; just don't make your development dependent on errors returned from foreign key violations, so they can be removed later without a code rewrite if it does become necessary.

All that said, this question is too general in it's current form. If you were to post examples of the tables, the question might not end up closed in a short amount of time.